# Is this answer to the limit correct? $\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+6}} $

Tags: calculus, limits

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+6}} $$

Shouldn't this limit be equal to 0 ? We divide the numerator and the denominator by $x^4$ and we get $1 / x^2$ in the numerator. So when x approaches infinity, the numerator becomes 0.

Comment: But then the denominator will also become $0$.

Comment: `We divide the numerator and the denominator by x^4 and ...` Apply the same line of thought to $x^2 / \sqrt{x^4}$. Find where it fails. Reconsider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you divide the numerator and denominator by $x^4$, you get
$$
  \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1/x^2}{\sqrt{(1/x^4)+(6/x^8)}}
$$
Plugging in $x = \infty$, the numerator and denominator are *both* $0$. So it is inconclusive.

We can instead divide the numerator and denominator by $x^2$. This gives us
$$
  \lim_{x\to \infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{1+(6/x^4)}}
$$
and plugging in $x = \infty$ we get $\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}} = 1$, which is the right answer.

Comment: You misspoke, you cannot plugin infinity, you meant the limit.

Comment: @ZelosMalum No, I did not misspeak. There is no problem plugging in $\infty$ to these expressions, or with arithmetic in general involving $\infty$ as long as you stop whenever you reach something like $\frac{\infty}{\infty}$ or $\infty - \infty$.

Comment: Infinity is not a real number so it is as meaningful saying "plug in apple", or more mathematicly "using integer multiplication what is 7 times the imaginary unit?" It's meaningless as that unit does not belong in integers so that operation is undefined.

Comment: @ZelosMalum OK, so I'm doing something differently than what you did in your freshman calculus class -- but do you *really* think that's the only way of doing things? Educate yourself on the [extended real numbers arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Arithmetic_operations).

Comment: no need, THERE it is legitimate, not in the reals and the poster did not say he worked with the extended reals. As for wrong, only in that instance of being rigorous but the idea itself, no.

Comment: @ZelosMalum As far as I can tell, you just want to pedantically insist that we only work in the real numbers when evaluating limits. But I refuse, I think the extended real numbers are useful when evaluating limits. And you made some ridiculous claims: e.g. that it is like saying "plug in an apple" -- of course it is not the same, I am saying to plug in an extended real number which is a well-defined thing as we both know. You are arguing against a **straw man** here.

Comment: The apple thing was to illustrate that plugging in things that do not belong in the structure is meaningless and by most conventions, unless otherwise states you work on the reals and as I said, nowhere in the original posters post does he state we work in the exntended real number line and as such $1/\infty$ is an invalid operation as the standard is the reals. But as said in the extended reals it is valid but again, nowhere is it stated we are dealing with the extended reals unless I missed it somewhere.

Comment: @ZelosMalum Nowhere is it stated we are dealing in the normal real numbers either. But my preferred interpretation of the limit as $x \to \infty$ **is** the limit in the extended reals and that is how I chose to answer. Additionally, even if we were not working in the extended reals, we may *pass to* the extended reals and evaluate the limit there. I don't see why you don't understand this, it's really not difficult.

Comment: The convention is unless otherwise stated it is reals one deal with, that is the default that does not need to be stated. And who said I don't understand? You are being imprecise, making buttload of assumptions and then portraying it as if it is a valid method to do in the reals alone. If you want ot do those things they are perfectly fine and legitimate but you should STATE you are doing that in yoru answer so less experienced people SEE what you are doing EXPLICITLY and don't get the wrong impression. It is answers like this that gives students flimsy ideas that makes them do errors.

Answer (score 3):

multiply the numerator and denominator by $1/x^2$.

Answer (score 2):

$$\lim_{x\to \infty} = \frac{x^2}{\sqrt{x^4+6}}=\lim_{x\to \infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+6/x^4}}=1 $$